# Why is django select2 not showing?

Tags: python, django, django-select2

put [django-select2](https://github.com/codingjoe/django-select2) on [this](https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) and [this](https://michelenasti.com/2021/02/12/how-to-integrate-a-django_select2-component-in-django-admin.html) instruction but select doesn't show what's wrong? cache specified, radish server set.

[image]

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django_select2',
]
```

**main urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('select2/', include('django_select2.urls')),
    ]
```

**app models.py**

```
class Clients(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$')
    phone = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17)
 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.phone
```

**app forms.py**

```
class PhoneSelect2Widget(s2forms.ModelSelect2Widget):
    search_fields = ('phone__icontains',)
    queryset = Clients.objects.all()

class RelatedAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    phone = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        widget=PhoneSelect2Widget(attrs={'class': 'select2'}),
        queryset=Clients.objects.all())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(RelatedAddForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Clients
        fields = ['phone']
```

**base.html**

```
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
    <!--begin::Head-->
    <head>
        <title>HUB CRM</title>
        {{ form.media.css }}
        <script src="{% static 'jquery/jquery-3.6.0.min.js' %}"></script
    ...
    ...
    {{ form.media.js }}
    </body>
    <!--end::Body-->
</html>
```